# How to change font size of a widget title in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I am rendering a Catalog Products List Widget to my Homepage. The title of the Widget is getting displayed over the product list, but it's far too small for my liking. How can I change the font-size or font-family of that title?

Comment: You can simply do it via css

Comment: Should I make the modifications in my _theme.less? And what class or variable to override?

Comment: Yes or your css file

Comment: Which class should I override to have the desired effect? I only want to change the font-size of a Widget title. Nothing else.

Comment: I dont know you code, your class name, inspect your code

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/css/style.css

```
.classname {
    font-size:...;
}
```

Then run :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```